# How to find the analytic continuation of this function

Tags: analytic-continuation

Lets say that I have the following function
$$f(x,\gamma)=\frac{x^{\gamma-2}}{(\gamma-2)!}+\frac{x^{\gamma-4}}{(\gamma-4)!}+...$$
$$f(x,\gamma)=x^\gamma\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{x^{-2k}}{(\gamma-2k)!}$$
When gamma is an integer:
$$f(x,1)=0$$
$$f(x,2)=1$$
$$f(x,3)=x$$
$$f(x,4)=1 + \frac{x^2}{2!} $$
$$f(x,n)=1+\frac{x^2}{2!}+ \frac{x^4}{4!}+...$$
where n is an even number. Ive tried the obvious extention
$$f(x,\gamma)=x^\gamma\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{x^{-2k}}{\Gamma(\gamma-2k + 1)}$$
However for non integer values the series still diverges, so how can I extend this for all possible inputs.

-----EDIT-------

I was thinking about using Ramanujan summation to look for an extension of this series that is convergent.

$$f(x,\gamma)=-x^\gamma\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{B_k}{k!} \frac{d^k}{dn^k}\left[\frac{x^{-2n}}{\Gamma(\gamma-2n+1)}\right]_{n=0}$$

Ive tried expressing it in the following form
$$f(x,\gamma)=-x^\gamma\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{B_k}{k!} \frac{d^k}{dn^k}\left[e^{-2n\ln x - \ln \Gamma(\gamma-2n+1)}\right]_{n=0}$$

$\ln \Gamma(\gamma-2n+1)$ is $\psi^{(-1)}(\gamma-2n+1)$

$$f(x,\gamma)=-x^\gamma\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{B_k}{k!} \frac{d^k}{dn^k}\left[e^{-2n\ln x - \psi^{(-1)}(\gamma-2n+1)}\right]_{n=0}$$

However Im struggling to find an expression for $\frac{d^k}{dn^k}\left[e^{-2n\ln x - \psi^{(-1)}(\gamma-2n+1)}\right]_{n=0}$. If anyone can find this expression that would be helpful.
Many Thanks Josh.

Comment: There exist a few methods to sum divergent series. They include Abel, Borel, Cesàro, Dirichlet, Euler, Lambert. Consult the list of [Summability methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Summability_methods) in Wikipedia. So far I have not gotten a method to sum your series. The problem is **not** one of analytic continuation.

Comment: @Somos Do you recon there will be another way of calculating this?

Comment: Your $\,f(x,n)\,$ is a variant of the truncated exponential series. In this case the truncations of $\,\sinh(x)\,$ and $\,\cosh(x).\,$ I don't think that there is a unique way to extend for nonintegers. Somewhat similar to extending Fibonacci sequence to reals. Note that $\,f(x,n) = f'(x,n+1)\,$ just as in the case of truncated exponential series.

Comment: You may be interested in  _An essay toward a unified theory of special functions_ by Clifford Truesdell published in 1948. It is based on the equation $\,\frac{\partial F(z,\alpha)}{\partial z}=F(z,\alpha+1).$

Comment: @Somos Looks cool, i'll check that out. The reason I wanted to do this is because it is connected to the reinnman zeta function. When this series goes to zero then it gives the zeta function in terms of pi